# Number of parallelpipeds

Tags: combinatorics

There are 4 points in space, not all lying in the same plane. How many distinct parallelepipeds can be constructed, if **these 4 points** are on its 8 vertices? 
Please I need a little help, how to start.

Comment: I think for one parallelepiped we need 8 points but here only 4 points are given

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all - choose 4 vertices in ${8\choose 4}$ ways
2. Exclude situations, when all selected vertices are on the same side ($6$ ways) or on two opposite (not lying on the same side) parallel edges ($6$ ways)
3. The final answer is then
   $$n={8\choose 4} - 12 = 58$$